# Deploying Matlab gui exe with Weka Models

Tags: matlab, weka, models

My problem is that when i deploy my Program along with weka models. The resulting error is that it cant read the weka model file.

Here is the structure of the Files

> ModelLoadmodel.m

Contains The ff code

```
javaaddpath('weka.jar');
addpath('SurfModels');
loadedModel = wekaLoadModel('RandomForestK40Surf.model');
```

The Folder wherein all of these file contains has a structure of

- WekaLoadmodel.m
- SurfRandomForestK40.model
- Folder"WekaLab" which has a

  - WekaLoadModel.m
  - Weka.jar

When i try to use the commandline function of

```
loadedModel = wekaLoadModel('RandomForestK40Surf.model');
```

The loadedModel is successfully loaded but when i deploy it using deploytool and the output is Error reading model file

The WekaLoadmodel.m Contains

```
if ~exist(filename, 'file')
    error('WEKALAB:wekaLoadModel:FileNotFound', 'No file found at %s', filename);
end
%% Code
try
    modelObj = weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(filename);
catch err
    error('WEKALAB:wekaLoadModel:ReadError', 'Error reading model file at %s', filename);
end
end
```

It came from https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/58675-wekalab--bridging-weka-and-matlab . Is there some sort of problem when loading other file extension in matlab deploytool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is don't put it in a folder. Just take all the .m files and compile it. Simple as that